# Grafana timeseries with Postgresql: GROUP BY doesn't work

Tags: postgresql, grafana

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "case_closed" (
"case_id" varchar(256) NOT NULL,
"closed_at" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,
"disposition" VARCHAR(128),
PRIMARY KEY ("case_id")
);
```

And in Grafana, I need to display more than one graph, one per each 'disposition' value (I have 2 different disposition values at the moment).

I'm trying this query:

```
SELECT
  $__timeGroupAlias(closed_at, $__interval),
  disposition AS "metric",
  COUNT(*) AS "value"
FROM case_closed 
WHERE 
  $__timeFilter(closed_at)
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 1
```

And it gives me this ugly picture with only one single graph:
[image]

I searched here and from all I can see my query seems to be okay, but it still doesn't work. Maybe I'm missing something and it's not the query but some settings??

Comment: I don't know Grafana, but I suspect you need to make a pivot table here to get the results for Disposition-1 in a separate column from the results for Disposition-2.

Comment: thanks for response! grafana is supposed to be able to extract that data, I saw examples as well as documentation

Answer (score 1):

Solved! There was a small thing in the Query Builder (not sure why I didn't see it in any documentation):
[image]